# Jenkins & NodeJS - job runs forever

Tags: node.js, jenkins, nodemon

I created a pipeline process for my NodeJS app, it gets the latest from Github and starts it.

The issue is that the jenkins job which starts the NodeJS app never stops - since the nodejs server process is still running.

How I can start the nodeJS server and complete the jenkins job?

I'm using nodemon as follows:

```
"start-prod": "npm run nodemon-prod",
"nodemon-prod": "nodemon --exec npm run production",
"production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./api/api.js",
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand correctly, but why do start the server on Jenkins? In our project we use Jenkins simply to build our typescript/node-app, run the unit-tests and then build/upload a docker image which later is deployed on K8s.

Comment: Thanks @eol, It's a personal project and I don't need much - I just want to restart it after every build(submit), when you say "later" is it manually?